# Bayesian logit model in Psychometric or Behavioural Testing for Credit Scoring in Developing Countries

Tags: credit-risk, credit-ratings, credit-scoring, bayes-theory, logit

A lot of parameters in one title, I know. So there's credit scoring but not using credit history. Then there's using a Bayesian logit model. Then there's doing so in a developing country such as Haiti or Peru.

Question: Does anyone know of any papers about psychometric or behavioural testing using Bayesian logit model to determine whether a loan applicant in a developing country would be creditworthy?

Background: [How can psychometric or behavioural tests be used in banking to evaluate creditworthiness?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10721/how-can-psychometric-or-behavioural-tests-be-used-in-banking-to-evaluate-creditw)

Something like they use psychological factors or questionnaires like in job interviews instead of financial factors such as financial ratios and then they have some methodology that reduces it to less factors then they make a regression model out of it or something but then they use Bayesian analysis or something there.

Edit: So far all I have found are [Enterprising Psychometrics and Poverty Reduction](http://www.hks.harvard.edu/fs/akhwaja/papers/EFLpaper2013.pdf)

[image]

and [Technical  Note    – EFL   Modeling    Methodology](https://www.eflglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/EFL-Technical-Note-July-2012_s.pdf).

Last part:

> RESULTS Here   we  illustrate  the     improved    performance     from    this
>   modeling   approach,   using   data    from    one    active  EFL country.

-

> Results    from    other   countries   show    the     same    result:     the     EFL
>   Bayesian   Hierarchical    Model
>   produces  more    accurate    predictions and more    stability   out-of-sample.

Reading this has already earned much appreciation.

Answering or commenting will merit much more.

Comment: Why don't you post this statistical question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Richard No idea why I did not think of that. Thanks!!! ^-^

Comment: Edited. Cross-posted http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164972/bayesian-logit-model-in-psychometric-or-behavioural-testing-for-credit-scoring-i